# Reference request: where is it written explicitly that the paradoxes of the early 20th century were overcame in the current mathematics?

Tags: logic, reference-request, math-history

Excuse me for this question, it continues [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953908/how-one-should-treat-m-klines-mathematics-the-loss-of-certainty).

I wonder if there is a text where it is written explicitly that the old paradoxes (like the Russell paradox, and the others) do not appear in the modern axiomatic set theories?

I need this as a reference to convince people in (Russian) Wikipedia that this is indeed so.

**EDIT.** From the downvotes and from Noah Schweber's answer I deduce that I have to explain my question in more detail.

Dear logicians, I do not need an explanation of why the paradoxes of the beginning of 20th century do not appear (or do not manifest themselves) in modern mathematics. I understand more or less clearly why it is so. I am asking about other thing:

> I need a book (or a paper) where it is written explicitly that those paradoxes indeed do not manifest themselves now in mathematics and do not pose a problem. **I do not need details, just statement.**

I need this reference for showing it to people who are not mathematicians, and **who still believe that those old paradoxes still pose problems for mathematics (and still make it inconsistent)**.

I think, it is difficult for you to imagine this, but such people exist. Moreover they have power as administrators of Russian Wikipedia, what allows them to publish [absurd articles about mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953908/how-one-should-treat-m-klines-mathematics-the-loss-of-certainty), containing lots of false propositions, and because of this I have to argue with them, and I believe that you, my colleagues, could help me in this. Instead of downvoting and sneering.

Hope this makes my question more clear.

**EDIT 2.** I see votes to close and I deduce from them that further explanations are still needed. I believe, my comment, addressed to Carl Mummert, will be mobilizing: this

> who still believe that those old paradoxes still pose problems for mathematics (and still make it inconsistent)

-- means that some people believe, that **all modern mathematics, including modern axiomatic set theories like ZFC, NBG, MK, is inconsistent and exactly because of the old paradoxes like Russell, Cantor, etc.**

And I now understand why they think so: **because there are no sources where it is written that this is not so. And because when you ask specialists about this, they theatrically do not understand what you are talking about, they sneer and they persist in talking about something else.**

I want to add here that it is not enough for me to refer to a book where the author explains why one of those old paradoxes (say Russell, or Cantor), "being translated into the formal language of the modern axiomatic set theory" that you consider, don't lead to a contradiction in this theory. Because this does not resolve the problem that I face: my opponents will say that this is the statement only about one paradox, not about all known paradoxes. And *logically* they will be right. Even the statement about several paradoxes, like in the reference that Noah Schweber gives (Evert Beth's book, page 495) does not resolve the problem. **There must be an explicit statement about all known paradoxes in a publication that will be accepted in Wikipedia as a reliable source.**

Does it exist?

**EDIT 3.** @AndrésE.Caicedo, @user21820, @Leucippus, @ChinnapparajR, @amWhy: could you please explain your reproach clealy? From the [instructions for "put on hold questions"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) I see that there is only one detail that can be considered missing in my post -- the description of what I was trying to do myself. I don't understand how this can help, but here are my attempts. I am not a specialist in logic, my field is analysis. I was trying to find the answers in encyclopedias. I did not succeed. The [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Main_Page) does not contain the article "Foundations of Mathematics". The article [Consistency](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Consistency) says nothing about what I need. The same for the "Mathematical Encyclopedic Dictionary"of 1988, which I have in Russian. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foundations_of_mathematics) does not contain reference that I need as well. I also asked several logicians in Moscow, again without success. That is actually all what came to my mind.

**EDIT 4.** [This chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47685637#47685637) shows me that despite my numerous explanations **some people believe that I am seeking a confession of consistency of mathematics. I never said this. What I need is a confession that no contradictions were found yet in ZFC, NBG and MK.** Please, think about the difference before reacting.

Comment: Nobody said that they were "overcame". But since they all came out of unrestricted comprehension, we removed it, and found no obvious way of repeating a proof of this paradox. So we're pretty happy with the results.

Comment: @Asaf, I need a reference. Where is it written that these paradoxes do not appear in the modern axiomatic set theories?

Comment: It's like you haven't read my comment.

Comment: Asaf, this also must be written in a book, not at a forum.

Comment: Right. Have a nice day.

Comment: A google-books search for ["paradoxes" + "set theory" + "overcome"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22paradoxes%22+%22set+theory%22+%22overcome%22&tbm=bks) gives (for me, at least) many possible places to look. However, being written in book does not guarantee general acceptance, and for something like this you should say "according to so-and-so, these paradoxes do not ..." rather than "these paradoxes do not ...". I could possibly pull down some set theory, foundations of math, math philosophy books from my bookshelves and hunt, but you'd still be relying on me that I am accurately quoting.

Comment: @Sergei Akbarov : What _seems_ to be being said here is that there is no _known_ way to create these kind of paradoxes in modern set theory, _but_ that that is _NOT_ a proof that such a way does _not_ exist, and it may be that no such proof exists.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer I don't understand. We can write at least some of those "propositions" literally as formulas in the language of set theory, and we'll see that they don't lead to paradoxes. I mean we don't come to a situation when a formula is deducible and its negation is deducible as well. I would call this "overcoming the paradox". What is the problem?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov I'll simplify history: before Cantor, everyone thought that naive set theory didn't lead to paradoxes. And yet it did. Who's to say that the next Cantor isn't about to prove ZF inconsistent?

Comment: @PatrickStevens but nobody prevents to write that up to now (with the corresponding date, say, November 18, 2018) the paradoxes in ZFC were not found. Is it written somewhere?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I see a list of publications in google search, but I don't see what I need among them.

Comment: You can start with a brief overview : [Paradoxes and Contemporary Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradoxes-contemporary-logic/) with a good biblio.

Comment: Also useful : [Russell's Paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/russell-paradox/).

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think your behavior is appropriate as a moderator.

Comment: @Hanno: Which part? Making comments on an answer, or making follow up comments on that?

Comment: For e.g. Russell's Paradox, see Jean van Heijenoort (editor), [From Frege to Gödel : A Source Book in Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=v4tBTBlU05sC&printsec=frontcover), Harvard UP (1967) : B.Russell, *Mathematical logic as based on the theory of types* (1908), page 163-on and E.Zermelo, *Investigations in the foundations of set theory* (1908), page 203.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, you indeed behave as if you followed some philosophy. It would be interesting to understand what kind of philosophy this is. :)

Comment: "who still believe that those old paradoxes still pose problems for mathematics (and still make it inconsistent)." - what does it mean to say that "mathematics" is inconsistent? Certainly the paradoxes show that many forms of informal "naive" mathematics are still as inconsistent as they ever were. We can only hope for formal theories to be consistent. Now PA is proved consistent to the standards of ordinary mathematical proof, but there is no such proof of the consistency of ZFC without additional assumptions.

Comment: @CarlMummert this means that some people believe, that **all modern mathematics, including modern axiomatic set theories like ZFC, NBG, MK, is inconsistent and exactly because of the old paradoxes like Russell, Cantor, etc.** And I now understand why: because there are no sources where it is written that this is not so. And because when you ask specialists about this, they theatrically do not understand what you are talking about, they sneer and they persist in talking about something else.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: no, most mathematicians *think* ZFC is consistent, but for various reasons they don't include "ZFC is consistent" among the axioms they take for granted, rather they explicitly include that statement as an assumption in theorems that require it. For example, instead of saying "ZFC does not prove the continuum hypothesis" they say "If ZFC is consistent it does not prove the continuum hypothesis".

Comment: At the same time, mathematicians *are not fundamentally motivated by whether something is stated explicitly in a source*. We work out what is going on for ourselves, to our own satisfaction. As a mathematician, there are many things stated in sources that I disagree with, even sources by mathematicians I respect, and there are many things I know that are not stated in any sources.  I suspect you may find that many people on this site will keep trying to write about the actual *mathematics* rather than what is in any particular source.

Comment: I would be glad to continue this conversation in the Logic chat room at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic . The chat rooms are persistent, so if someone posts there another person can reply later.

Comment: Carl, it seems to me in that chat we hinder other people.

Comment: Okay, so what is wrong with the quote I give in that same chat room? https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47685714#47685714

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen at the moment I don't see any problems with this quote. I need a time for finding this book and reading it. Thank you.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I am reading this place in Ebbinghaus-Flum-Thomas. The phrase seems appropriate, but the verb "attests" is a bit strange: "Nevertheless, the fact that ZFC has been investigated and used in mathematics for decades and no inconsistency has been discovered, **attests** to the consistency of ZFC". This sounds frivolous. I forsee accusations in using unreliable sources.

Comment: Well, it’s a reputable textbook. I’m not sure what the problem is with the word “attests”... they are just saying “nobody has found an inconsistency, so it’s probably consistent.” One might reasonably disagree with the “so it’s probably consistent” part, but the “nobody has found an inconsistency” part is very clear.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen we discussed this here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47694876#47694876 In Merriam-Webster "attests" is a synonim of "proves" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attest In translation into Russian they become synonims as well. I think, its impossible to convince Russians that your translation is correct.

Comment: "no inconsistency has been found in ZFC" is clear, but together with  "attests to the consistency" this casts doubt on the seriousness of the source for people who don't speak English well and have to trust dictionaries.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think self-satisfied cynicism as in your second and third comment ever gets you anywhere in a discussion; I found it especially misplaced because, while technically fine as always, your first comment did indeed not address the OP's request for a reference. You're better than that...

Comment: @Hanno: That might be true, but the first comment *did* comment on the question, and on the subtleties of saying that "ZFC is paradox free", to which the OP replied in a manner I found odd, when I commented on *that*, I got a reply that it should appear "in a book". I'm not sure what one (not me specifically) should say in a situation like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many sources that claim no inconsistencies have been found in ZF (or ZFC, which is known to be consistent if ZF is consistent.)

- Ershov and Palyutin on p. 92 of *Mathematical Logic* write: "What can be said about the consistency of ZFC? No inconsistencies have been discovered in ZFC itself this far."
- Ebbinghaus, Flum and Thomas on p. 12 of *Mathematical Logic* write "Nevertheless, the fact that ZFC has been investigated and used in mathematics for decades and no inconsistency has been discovered, attests to the consistency of ZFC."
- Bloch on p. 120 of *Proofs and Fundamentals: A First Course in Abstract Mathematics* 2nd ed writes "However, even if no one has definitively proved that the ZF axioms are consistent, we observe that these axioms have been designed to remove the known problems of naive set theory such as Russell’s Paradox. ... Ultimately, the ZF axioms seem reasonable intuitively; they work well in providing a framework for set theory as we would want it; the known problems with naive
  set theory have been eliminated by the ZF axioms; and experts in the field have not found any new problems that arise out of these axioms. Hence, we can feel confident that the ZF axioms are a very reasonable choice as the basis for mathematics. We simply cannot do any better than that."

There are many more texts which say essentially the same thing.

As many authors note, including all I mentioned above, the incompleteness theorem prevents us from having a proof of the consistency of ZF that is formalizable in ZF - which many authors feel precludes any sort of finitistic consistency proof.

So we are left with the situation that, although we can only prove the consistency of ZF by assuming sufficiently strong axioms, few mathematicians treat ZF as if they expect it to be inconsistent.

Comment: Carl, I found Ershov-Palyutin in Russian. In which section do they write this?

Comment: Ah, yes, I found this! In Russian version this is also page 92. Thank you!

Comment: Here's another quote. Penelope Maddy, "Set Theory as a Foundation," in Foundational Theories of Classical and Constructive Mathematics (Springer, 2011) says in a footnote, "ZFC is not prone to Russell's (or any other known) paradox."

Answer (score 4):

Discussions of the resolution of Russell's paradox by restricting the comprehension axiom(s) can be found in most introductory set theory textbooks. For example, just search for "Russell": this works for [Kunen's book](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf) (page $19$), [Jech's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540440852) (page $4$), ... When in doubt, search!

As a specific example, page $20$ of Barr and Wells' freely-available book [Category theory for computing science](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/triples/Barr-Wells-ctcs.pdf) sums up the situation quite succinctly:

> A simple way to avoid this paradox is to restrict x to range over a particular type of data (such as one of the various number systems – real, integers, etc.) that already forms a set. This prophylaxis guarantees safe sets.

For a discussion of the resolution of the Burali-Forti paradox, see Hellman's article [On the significance of the Burali-Forti paradox](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41340712?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) (second paragraph).

---

Meanwhile, most other paradoxes (e.g. the Liar, [Berry's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox), [Hilbert-Bernays' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Bernays_paradox), ...) have nothing to do with set theory per se, but are rather about *logic itself*: they essentially amount to the observation that *if we could define a truth predicate* in any context sufficiently strong to [accommodate basic self-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_lemma), we would get a contradiction. Viewed this way, these aren't *paradoxes* but rather *theorems* (e.g. [Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) or [Chaitin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Chaitin's_incompleteness_theorem)) about first-order logic, and we don't look to set theory for their resolutions.

---

One takeaway from the above is that the resolutions are *always the same*: the obvious route to paradox is blocked right at the outset, either by not having the needed axiom (e.g. full comprehension vs. separation/restricted comprehension) or not having the relevant object "built in" to the logical framework (e.g. truth predicate). I don't know of a single paradox of naive reasoning whose resolution in ZFC with classical logic is nontrivial. Once one understands how to resolve the liar and Russell's paradox, everything else is an easy exercise. This is why the citations one finds are often perfunctory: there just isn't very much to say.

This isn't to say that the topic *can't* be interesting; there are definitely instances of systems avoiding a contradiction in clever ways. But the point is that classical logic + ZFC isn't one of those: it avoids the paradoxes in the most basic way possible.

Comment: Noah, I edited my question so that it could be more clear.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov But I *have* included an explicit reference stating that (and linked to three others). Is it not explicit enough, or not strong enough, somehow?

Comment: Noah, which one?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Kunen, Kunen, Jech, Barr/Wells on Russell's paradox and Hellman on Burali-Forti's paradox; see the first part of my answer.

Comment: Noah I don't see in the first Kunen the statement that I need. At pages 10-11 he mentiones just Russell. The same for others. Is there a book with the general statement, about all old paradoxes?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov You're right about the first reference; Kunen mentions the role of not allowing $y$ to be free in the applying formula, which is important but not what you're asking. But re: "The same for others": quoting from Jech: "The safe way to eliminate paradoxes of this type is to abandon the Schema of Comprehension and keep its weak version, the Schema of Separation: If $P$ is a property, then for any $X$ there exists a set $Y =\{x\in X :P(x)\}$. Once we give up the full Comprehension Schema, Russell’s Paradox is no longer a threat." That seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov Similarly, from the other Kunen example: "Cantor’s advice was to avoid inconsistent sets (see [10]). This avoidance was incorporated into Zermelo’s statement of the Comprehension Axiom as it is in Section I.2. Namely, once you *have* a set $z$, you can form $\{x \in z : Q(x)\}$. You can still form $R = R_z = \{x \in z : x \not\in x\}$, but this only implies that *if* $R \in z$, then $R \in R \leftrightarrow R \not\in R$,
which means that $R\not\in z$."

Comment: Noah, I am asking about all paradoxes, not only about Russell.

Comment: And I gave another example for Burali-Forti. And I explained why the others aren't about set theory. Do you want me to add sources on why they're not a problem for *logic*? Regardless, it seems to me - based on the ease with which I'm finding sources in standard textbooks - that you haven't really conducted a thorough search on your own, and I think it's this that's lead to a downvote.

Comment: Noah, I can't refer to your answer at this website, this is not allowed in Wikipedia. When asking this I thought that there is something like encyclopedia where this is explained. Is it possible that there is no such a source? And you are not right, I tried to seek.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "It can be made clear that those arguments which in Cantor's original version of set theory
gave rise to paradoxes are eliminated in virtue of the restrictions implied by the axiomatisations which Zermelo and others have given." From Evert Beth's article [The paradoxes of logic and set theory and their solution](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X09703301) (page $495$). Better?

Comment: (I wrote "article," but it's actually a chapter in Beth's book. Oh well.)

Comment: Better. But not enough clear, I forsee problems in explaining the meaning. Is there a direct statement?

Comment: I forsee a problem in this phrase: "The paradoxes of set theory — that is, the paradoxes of Cantor, of Burali-Forti, and of Zermelo-Konig — apparently originate from the liberality with which the comprehension axiom allows the introduction of new sets." The opponents will say that Beth speaks about three paradoxes, while we need a statement about all known paradoxes.